# Apache POI xlsx read error "limit exceeds 65536 methods for dex file" Android

Tags: android, apache, apache-poi

I trying to read xlsx files using POI library in Android. There are five jar files. 3 of them are main rest are dependencies. If i exclude any i get errors(class missing).

When i include all 5 jars in my project(sample empty project), it doesn't compiles and give error methods limit exceeds 65536 that dex can have. I have tried following to figure this out:

1. enabled project proguard
2. try to create multiple dex files, but due to dependencies problem, i m unable to put them in separate dex file.
3. enabled to dex.force.jumbo =true in project properties  but didn't work.

I m trying following code

```
public void getto()
{
    int totalRows;
    String destDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Download/csv_contract_sample2.xlsx";
    try { 
        System.out.println("destDir==> "+destDir); 
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(destDir); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0); 
        totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); 
        System.out.println("total no of rows >>>>"+totalRows); 

        } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
}
```

It is working perfectly fine if i create a java project. But for Android above problem is there. Is there a good solution or any other library for xlsx read?

Comment: try with SXSSFWorkbook.

Comment: @swamy but that is for write operation only. i want to read. Does it support read operation also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xls is a zip file. So we can extract zip and get xml files inside and then we can parse it ourself to get sheet data.

This will work for both For both xls and xlsx.

Comment: Only xlsx is a zip. Xls is a binary format that is quite complicated to parse.

Answer (score -1):

There is even no other API than POI available to read xlsx file.

Comment: there are couple of libraries available like Saaspose and docx4java but they are not working for me.